# VSCode 1.22.2: Emmet disappeared?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I made the switch to VSCode about a month ago and I'm really into it, been using Sublime for years and VSCode is everything I always wanted, plus things I didn't even know I wanted!

But, so, today I was working on a project and noticed that t**he Emmet functionality stopped working**. In all the languages I work with, not just one. I couldn't remember if Emmet was native in VSCode or if I installed it as a extension because when I checked, there was no sign of it. I tried searching for the extension to no avail. I seem to have a faint memory that it was already featured without having to install it separately. Am I imagining this?

I disabled any other extension that might have a keybinding conflict with the tab functionality, notably ESLint but that didn't seem to do anything. Worth mentioning, too- this all happened out of no where: no new extensions, no new files, this was the same project folder I've been working on for a week now, a collection of MySQL and NodeJS files. I have no idea what happened.

Any insight would be really appreciated! It's crazy going from using Emmet for years to not having it and realizing how robot-reflex it made me, oy!

Thank you!

Comment: Also maybe worth noting- in the meantime, until I can diagnose what happened, I moved back to Sublime just to finish the project I've been working on. The emmet functionality is sorely needed for it's a freelance project with a lot of data being formatted into crazy complicated ul / li structures and the emmet workflow seriously saves so much time. Emmet is a completely different package installed in Sublime, I know, but I thought that it might be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured it out-
in my preferences, I had switched off suggestions for a little project I was working on that was getting in way with suggestions I didn't need.

If anyone else is running into this problem, try adding this into your preferences json-
**editor.quickSuggestions: true**